# Table Rates not working with multiple website environment magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3

> Table rate not working with multiple website with catalog price scope
>   set to global.

Also we have multiple currency setup website vise.

Magento version 2.3.3

There was two kind of issue.

1.if i set catalog price scope set to Website, currency conversion working fine but table rate not working and always apply default main website's table rates.

2.if i set catalog price scope set to Global , currency conversion not working but table rate working fine.